# Send AWS Budget Alerts with Custom Message Body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

I'm trying to set up AWS budget alerts with custom message body. For example, I need to include the percentage at which the alert was triggered. Below is the default message body. Is there anyway I can change it?

```
Dear AWS Customer,
 
You requested that we alert you when the actual cost associated with your ***** budget exceeds $****** for the current month. The month actual cost associated with this budget is $*****. You can find additional details below and by accessing the AWS Budgets dashboard.
 
BudgetName|BudgetType|BudgetedAmount|AlertType|AlertThreshold|ACTUALAmount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the template AWS Budgets uses for sending emails.

Instead of having AWS Budgets send the alert directly to an email, you could have AWS Budgets send the alert to an SNS topic. You would then create a Lambda function that is subscribed to the SNS topic, and have the Lambda function parse the event message, and use that to construct your custom email, and send the email via AWS SES.